# I wonder why Michael Spivak assumed $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" Axler

Tags: uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

The following theorem is in "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

> THEOREM 1 (p.503)
> Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions which are integrable on $[a,b]$, and that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a function $f$ which is integrable on $[a,b]$. Then $$\int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b f_n.$$

The following is Exercise 14 in Exercises 1A in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

> Suppose $f_1,f_2,\dots$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ such that $f_1,f_2,\dots$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable and $$\int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b f_n.$$

I wonder why Michael Spivak assumed $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Any reason?

Comment: To make the exercise easier, presumably.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you very much for your comment. But THEOREM1 (on p.503) is not an exercise.

Comment: Then to make the proof of the theorem easier. Or perhaps he didn’t notice he didn’t need to assume $f$ is integrable. Mathematicians don’t always notice the strongest version of a theorem is true, and they don’t always go to the effort of proving the most general case. There isn’t really a deep mystery here.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you very much for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

I found the following Problem (Problem 26 on p.523 in "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak).

> 26 (a)
> Prove that if $f$ is the uniform limit of $\{f_n\}$ on $[a,b]$ and each $f_n$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $f$. (So one of the hypotheses in Theorem 1 was unnecessary.)

I also found that Michael Spivak really assumes that the reader will solve all the problems.

Comment: @Kyky I tried to prove that $f$ is integrable. Please see the link  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4638912/384082 We are talking about Riemann-integrability. Thank you.